# Expiration of IPhone AdHoc Tester Provisioning Profiles

Tags: iphone, profile, provisioning, adhoc

Is it possible to renew an adhoc tester's provisioning profile PRIOR to expiration?  Currently, it seems I have to wait for it to expire before I can renew it -- which means that my testers lose a day of testing while waiting for me to renew the profile and mail it to them.

Answer (score 0):

testers can have more than one profile installed, so you can just send a brand new mobileprovision file along with a testing build, so you won't have this problem unless there's enough time between builds for a profile to expire.

Comment: My adhoc testers reported that the apps stopped working instantly when the original profiles expired.  So they then contact me, and I go to developer.apple.com and renew the profiles.  Until I do that, they can't test.  And developer.apple.com won't let you renew until it expires.  Catch-22?

Comment: how long was your app in test for?  my point was that if you're sending them a new build you can make a new provisioning file and sign the new build of your app with the new file, and as long as they're not planning to "test" that new build for months, they'll be okay.

Comment: David -- Thanks for your interest and tips so far.  I might be missing something.  I don't know how to make a provisioning profile until the old one expires.  On Developer.apple.com, the "Renew" button does not appear until the old one expires.

Comment: there's an "edit" choice on profiles that lets you add additional devices, for instance... so you can basically make a new version of the same profile and then use that new one to sign your app and distribute it (and the new profile) to your users.